# ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_IP and network loss

Tags: ros, ros-ip, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two laptops, one with a running roscore, the other has running nodes connected to the roscore in the first laptop.
I noticed that I have to run both launch files using the ROS_IP set to the laptop IP address, in particular, in this case, to the wlan0 card IP address. On the second laptop, I also set the ROS_MASTER_URI variable, so that it connects to the first one's roscore.

The problem is when there is a wireless connection loss, ROS master starts complying about network loss, some node dies, and, however, after a reconnection, things do not reactivate, I have to stop the launch and restart.

Is there any way to avoid this? In a robot world a wireless network loss is a probable event.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198969/ros_master_uri,-ros_ip-and-network-loss/) by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not currently have any mechanism for dealing with dropped connections.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0